# c# retrieve facebook page insights with console application

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, console-application, facebook-insights

I need to write a program that will retrieve facebook insights from a page I'm the administrator of. I have to use a console app because there are other things that I must do later with the data. My problem is with logging in automatically. I created a facebook application but after doing some research I saw that for reading a facebook page insights I must first login to obtain an access token, which would allow me to obtain a manage_page permission.

So my question is how do I obtain user access token with the console app in C#?

var fb = new FacebookClient();

but then what?

Comment: have you tried a google search and or consulted with the `FaceBook SDK` try looking at this link as it seems someone has asked this same question before - https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebooksdk.net%2Fdocs%2Ffaq%2F&ei=jg3_VNWNFJSfyAS96oBg&usg=AFQjCNFRCVy9l_Y9zzmyb12RfJysTjRc5Q&bvm=bv.87611401,d.aWw

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks, but already seen that, I've been reading for a while all the documentation I can find. In that link is described how to take access token for facebook app which i can do. But you can't retrieve all the information you need from a Page. What I don't know how to do is Get user access token but with console app, without forms and without putting manualy username and password.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to learn how to code an Insights application is to use the Getting Started wizard. You can find Getting Started session in https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[app_id]/marketing-api/
Basically you can pick metrics and the wizard will generate a working code for you. (It is only generating Java code for now)

Also if you don't really wants to code, you may try the new product we just released called Facebook Ads Manager for Excel. It allows you to download Insights data into Excel directly. More info:

https://www.facebook.com/business/m/facebook-ads-manager-for-excel